# Build failed of downloaded .mcp file in MPLAB for PIC18F2550 and PIC18F4550

Tags: pic, mplab

I have installed **Mplab** version 8.9, I have downloaded a firmware package from this [link](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device)

But, when I hit `build all` it shows me the following output and build fails:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Debug build of project `D:\microchip\WFF Generic HID Demo 3\WFF_GenericHID_Demo_3.mcp' started.
Language tool versions: mplink.exe v9.80, mcc18.exe v9.80, mplib.exe v9.80
Preprocessor symbol `__DEBUG' is defined.
Thu May 29 15:44:49 2014
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Make: The target "D:\microchip\WFF Generic HID Demo 3\main.o" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.31\bin\mcc18.exe" -p=18F4550 /i"..\Microchip Solutions v2011-07-14\Microchip\Include" "main.c" -fo="main.o" -D__DEBUG -Ou- -Ot- -Ob- -Op- -Or- -Od- -Opa-

Make: The target "D:\microchip\WFF Generic HID Demo 3\usb_descriptors.o" is out of date.
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.31\bin\mcc18.exe" -p=18F4550 /i"..\Microchip Solutions v2011-07-14\Microchip\Include" "usb_descriptors.c" -fo="usb_descriptors.o" -D__DEBUG -Ou- -Ot- -Ob- -Op- -Or- -Od- -Opa-

usb_descriptors.c:
   125: rom struct{BYTE report[28];}hid_rpt01={
                   (984) type redeclared ^
                                         ^ (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "hid_rpt01" (usb_descriptors.c:125)
(908) exit status = 1
(908) exit status = 1
Halting build on first failure as requested.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Debug build of project `D:\microchip\WFF Generic HID Demo 3\WFF_GenericHID_Demo_3.mcp' failed.
Language tool versions: mplink.exe v9.80, mcc18.exe v9.80, mplib.exe v9.80
Preprocessor symbol `__DEBUG' is defined.
Thu May 29 15:44:51 2014
----------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILED
```

I tried to find the problem in this [link](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=917) also, but i could not find its root cause.

I started to try this because i wanted to make my own shields and pcb for my projects instead of `arduino` and the like.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Within the linked article, under '[Installing and building the firmware source](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device#Installing_and_building_the_firmware_source_code)', there are a few notes made in regards to ensuring the Application Library install directory is named appropriately - and to correct missing files due to relative vs absolute paths.  Had you run into any of those issues?

Comment: Another thing mentioned in the article that might be relevant:  'The firmware is only tested against version 2.9a of the stack (which is contained in the v2011-07-14 installer)' -- can you verify that is the version of the Microchip Application Library that you are building against?